# getting the owner of the folder with the if command

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

i want to be able to prevent people from accidentally deleting critical files of the system in my my script, does anyone know how to use the statement to find if the owner of the folder?

Comment: Your question can be answered by "yes" (someone knows) or "no" (nobody knows). Is that really going to help you? Please edit your post and include your script, so we can see **how** people could accidentally remove files (by giving the wrong arguments/by executing it in the wrong directory/by executing it at the wrong phase of moon),

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find . -prune -user "$(id -u)"
```

Will print `.` if the current directory is owned by you.

You can either do:

```
find . -prune -user "$(id -u)" -exec some command \;
```

Or:

```
if [ -n "$(find . -prune -user "$(id -u)")" ]; then
  some command
fi
```

To run `some command` only if the current directory is owned by you.

Most implementations of `test` aka `[` including the builtin one of the `zsh`, `bash`, `ksh`, `dash`, `yash` and `bosh` shells have `-O` (that's capital O) for that as well:

```
if [ -O . ]; then
  some command
fi
```

The `zsh` shell also has the `U` glob qualifier to select files owned by you. So a similar approach to the `find` one could be done with:

```
if ()(($#)) .(NU); then
  some command
fi
```

To retrieve the id of the current directory's owner, POSIXly, you can do:

```
ownerid=$(LC_ALL=C ls -lnd . | awk '{print $3}')
```

Or, with `zsh`'s `stat` builtin:

```
stat -LH stat . && ownerid=$stat[uid]
```

Or with GNU `find`:

```
ownerid=$(find . -prune -printf %U)
```

Or with GNU `stat`:

```
ownerid=$(stat -c %u .)
```

Or, with BSD `stat`:

```
ownerid=$(stat -f %u .)
```

Once you have that `$ownerid`, you can compare that to the effective user id of your shell's process which you can get with `"$(id -u)"`. Generally, it's better to work with user ids than usernames as there can be more than one username per user id in the account database (and that saves having to query that user database).

Answer (score 2):

Wait, what? To prevent people from deleting critical system files, don't let them log in as root and don't make your script setuid.

If you're trying to help people manage files that do not belong to them, learn about group permissions and use a suitable set-up. (I can't say more since I don't know what you're up to.)

If root rights are really necessary (to let regular users manage system logs, for example), use a "whitelist" approach: Your script should only manage files that match specific criteria. Otherwise, who knows what important resource you'll forget to protect?

Comment: While I agree with this answer, I also think it's useful to have [checks to prevent you from making mistakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poka-yoke) when you do and *should* have permission to make them.  A good example of this is the alteration of `rm` in many distros to prevent accidental `rm -rf /`s.

Comment: And I agree with your statement. But the use case here is to protect "critical system files" by checking _if the target folder belongs to the user._ Clearly, if you're only supposed to remove your own resources, you should not be running with superuser rights. In your own folder, you don't need setuid privileges to remove someone else's files. Subdirectories are harder, but that's best handled in advance by setting the folder permissions properly. (Again, I would have given specifics but it's not clear what the OP is up to.)